# Random sampling using running length encoding (rle)

Tags: r

Is it possible to perform a sampling without replacement? Something like this (it does not work as desired):

```r
x <- rle(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2))

result <- sample(x, size=2, replace=F)

print(inverse.rle(result))
# prints [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2
# a desired result [1] 1 1
```

In other words, I'd like to have the following working but with running length encoding:

```r
set.seed(2)  
x <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2)

result <- sample(x, size=2, replace=F)

print(result)
# prints [1] 1 2
```

Comment: You are applying `sample` on a `list` of length 2.  May be you want to sample the `values`?

Comment: Which is why it does not work, I'm just wondering if there's a method to perform sampling with rle objects without decompressing them

Comment: when you specify size = 2, then are you subsetting elements that have length 2?  In this example, there are only two 'values'.  Perhaps a better example would clarify

Comment: I'm not sure where your confusion stems from. I want size to be used as intended, "size: a non-negative integer giving the number of items to choose". I'll add some extra info

Comment: I guess, then you may need to `sample(inverse.rle(x), size =2, replace = FALSE)`  based on the `sample` applied on the vector, it is on the whole vector,

Comment: yeah that'd work, but as I said, I'd like to perform this operation without decompressing. Statistically is not complicated, so maybe there's already a package/function that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function to do it. You probably need some big numbers to make this worthwhile over just expanding out the rle explicitly.

```
x <- rle(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2))

sample_rle <- function(x, ...) {
  x$values[1+findInterval(
    sample(sum(x$lengths), ...),
    cumsum(x$lengths), 
    left.open=TRUE)]
}

sample_rle(x, size = 2, replace = FALSE)
#> [1] 2 1
sample_rle(x, size = 7, replace = FALSE)
#> [1] 2 1 2 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, yes the main reason I was looking for this is to avoid running into memory/speed issues with big data

Answer (score 0):

The sampling works out of the box if instead of `rle()` you use the S4Vectors function `Rle()`.

```
x <- Rle(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2))
# numeric-Rle of length 7 with 2 runs
# Lengths: 5 2
# Values : 1 2
xs <- sample(x, 4, replace=F)
# numeric-Rle of length 4 with 2 runs
# Lengths: 2 2
# Values : 2 1
xs2 <- Rle(sort(xs))
# numeric-Rle of length 4 with 2 runs
# Lengths: 2 2
# Values : 1 2
as.vector(xs2)
# [1] 1 1 2 2
```